# Create a vector with multiple expressions

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following ggplot barchart. How can I generate a vector with multiple expressions automatically?

```
data <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:11], y = 10^(0:10))
z <- 0:10
y.labels <- sprintf(paste0("10^", z))
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = 10^(z), labels = y.labels)
```

I've tried with `bquote(.(10^c(z)))`, but is not the desired result .

My only alternative is to do it manually, but it is not automatic:

```
y.labels <- expression("10"^0, "10"^1, "10"^2, "10"^3, "10"^4, "10"^5, "10"^6, "10"^7, "10"^8, "10"^9, "10"^10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `parse(text =`, which will convert the character vector `y.labels` into the expected expression:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_log10(breaks = 10^(z), labels = parse(text = y.labels))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `bquote` with `expression`

```
y.labels <-  sapply(z, function(u) as.expression(bquote(10^.(u))))
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
   scale_y_log10(breaks = 10^(z), labels =y.labels)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to store both `z` and `y.labels`, you can use:

```
library(scales)
data <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:11], y = 10^(0:10))
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks(log10, function(x) 10^x, 10), 
                labels = trans_format(log10, math_format(10^.x)))
```